# wamp server session with genymotion

Tags: retrofit2, wampserver, genymotion

I can't keep the wampserver session when using genymotion with Android. all is ok with localhost (pc) but not with the genymotion emulator. I use retrofit 2.

Here is my code:

```
     <?php
          header('Content-type: application/json');
          session_start();
          if(isset($_SESSION['email'])  && isset($_SESSION['firstName']) 
          && isset($_SESSION['lastName']) ){
              $data["data"] = array(array("result" =>"connected"));
              echo json_encode($data);

          }else{
              $data["data"] = array(array("result" =>"log out"));
              echo json_encode($data);
       }

     ?>
```

json result returns log out. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem  , i have  used shared preferences to save my profile 's data